# Selector jquery no funciona

Tags: html, jquery

Como quedaria el selector para tomar el objeto:

```
<label class="caja caja1-seccion1">?</label>
```

Este es el codigo completo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo trato de seleccionar asi : $('.operacion1.caja')  pero no funciona.

Comment: Te falta un espacio entre `.operacion1` y `.caja`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al escribir `$('.operacion1.caja')` estas buscando un objeto DOM que contenga ambas clases. Lo que tu buscas es esto:

```
$('.operacion1 > .caja')
```

Cabe notar que como alternativa se puede realizar en dos selecciones mediante los siguientes métodos

```
$('.operacion1').find('.caja') //busca en todos los niveles dentro de .operacion1
$('.operacion1').children('.caja') //busca solamente un nivel dentro de .operacion1
```

Answer (score 0):

Para seleccionar el objeto:

```
<label class="caja caja1-seccion1">?</label>
```

Puedes hacerlo perfectamente mediante sus dos clases: `caja` y `caja1-seccion1`, sin espacios.

No te funcionaba porque lo que intentabas seleccionar era los elementos con las clases `.operacion1.caja`.

En el ejemplo lo voy a seleccionar y a poner un color naranja de fondo y verás que funciona.

```js
var mLabel=$('.caja.caja1-seccion1');
console.log (mLabel.text());
mLabel.css("background-color", "orange");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="caja caja1-seccion1">?</label> <br />
<label class="simbolo">+</label> <br />
<label class="caja caja2-seccion1">?</label> <br />
```